# I'm getting same MAE value in decision tree model for maxdepth value from 1 to 10

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

R code :

```
library(tidyverse) # utility functions
library(rpart) # for regression trees
library(randomForest) # for random forests
library(modelr)

split_data = resample_partition(melb_data,c(test=.3,train=.7))

get_mae <- function(maxdepth, target, predictors, training_data, testing_data){


predictors <- paste(predictors, collapse="+")
formula <- as.formula(paste(target,"~",predictors,sep = ""))


model <- rpart(formula, data = training_data,
             control = rpart.control(maxdepth = maxdepth))

mae <- mae(model, testing_data)
return(mae)
}

target <- "Price"
predictors <-  c("Rooms","Bathroom","Landsize","BuildingArea",
             "YearBuilt","Lattitude","Longtitude")

for(i in 1:10){
mae <- get_mae(maxdepth = 3, target = target, predictors = predictors, training_data = split_data$train, testing_data = split_data$test)
print(glue::glue("Maxdepth: ",i,"\t MAE: ",mae))
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Maxdepth: 1  MAE: 356628.697268696  
Maxdepth: 2  MAE: 356628.697268696  
Maxdepth: 3  MAE: 356628.697268696  
Maxdepth: 4  MAE: 356628.697268696  
Maxdepth: 5  MAE: 356628.697268696  
Maxdepth: 6  MAE: 356628.697268696  
Maxdepth: 7  MAE: 356628.697268696  
Maxdepth: 8  MAE: 356628.697268696  
Maxdepth: 9  MAE: 356628.697268696  
Maxdepth: 10 MAE: 356628.697268696
```

Comment: Did I answer it?

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
for(i in 1:10){mae <- get_mae(maxdepth = 3, target = target, predictors = predictors, training_data = split_data$train, testing_data = split_data$test)}
```

You are setting `maxdepth` to 3 for every `i`. You have to change it for:

```
for(i in 1:10){mae <- get_mae(maxdepth = i, target = target, predictors = predictors, training_data = split_data$train, testing_data = split_data$test)}
```